# How to get a transformation of a function as a return?

Tags: python, function

My objective is to implement the following system (Taken from signal processing schematic-*ish*):
[image]

Now, X[n] could be any signal, any function, for simplicity and for testing the program we could see it as the exponential function. And as the signal goes along the subsystems it undergoes some transformations, for S1 the transformation is:

[image]

and after S2 is:

[image]

and so far I have done this:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

n=np.arange(-20,20)
y=np.zeros(n.shape)
x=np.exp(n)

def S1(inputSign, x_values, finalSys=True):
    if finalSys==True:
        output=np.zeros(x_values.shape)
        for i in range(len(x_values)):
            if x_values[i]%2==0:
                output[i]=inputSign(x_values[i]/2)
            else:
                output[i] = 0
        return output
    else:
        return inputSign



def S2(inputSign, x_values, finalSys=True):
    if finalSys==True:
        output=np.zeros(x_values.shape)
        for i in range(len(x_values)):
            output[i]=inputSign(x_values)+0.5*inputSign(x_values)+0.25*inputSign(x_values)
        return output
    else:
        return inputSign+0.5*?????
```

Now the functions are defined with a condition finalSys that is supposed to be that if it is the last system it gives me an array of values. The objective is to "cascade"(S2(S1,n,finalSys=True), maybe not the correct term) the functions to as to get a final answer dependent only of the initial input signal but transformed along the way by the subsystems. I could do it manually and get an expression to the resulting system but I am doing this as a learning exercise so please bear with me. My trouble has been how to alter the arguments of the inputSign. As an example, S1(np.exp,n,finalSys=False)(2) should return the same as np.exp(1).

Comment: Can you explain clearly, what are you trying to do here?

Comment: I'll edit it for clarity

Comment: @Bidon, when the function is "called later" will it be passed an array of values similar to `x_values`?

Comment: @Arihant , I have edited it. It should be more clear what my goal is now.

Comment: @fountainhead , please see the edit. It's clearer about what the goal is. Thank you

Comment: I see a possible inconsistency between your S1 function, and your definition of S1 in the image. The image says `x[n/2]`, but your Python code says `x[n]/2`. Or, did I mis-interpret your image?